# Set default value on dynamically filled drop down in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there an easy way to select default value when drop down is populated with data that is dynamically generated?

I have drop down that is populated with values for hours (actually every 15 minutes: ...,09:15, 09:30, 9:45, 10:00, 10:15, ...)

What I want to do is to select by default on page loading value 12:00 (noon).

I know that there is a way to do this by giving index of value, but I wanted to explore is there some better way to do it maybe?

This is my drop down:

```
<div class="col-md-2" ng-class="{ 'has-error has-feedback': addNewTestSession.sessionStartTime.$touched && addNewTestSession.sessionStartTime.$invalid }">
    <label for="sessionStartTime">Session Start Time<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <select id="sessionStartTime" name="sessionStartTime" class="form-control" 
        ng-model="newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionTime"
        ng-options="time for time in newTestSessionCtrl.viewData.sessionStarTimeIntervals"
        ng-required="true">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    </select>
    <span ng-show="addNewTestSession.sessionStartTime.$touched && addNewTestSession.sessionStartTime.$invalid" 
        class="fa fa-warning form-control-feedback"
        uib-popover="This field is required." 
        popover-trigger="'mouseenter'"
        popover-placement="auto right"
        popover-class="additional-info"></span>             
</div>
```

And this function will generate data for it:

```
sessionStarTimeIntervals: this.generateTimeIntervalArray(15)

generateTimeIntervalArray(minutes) {
    let retVal = [];
    let hour = 0;
    let minute = 0;
    let whileTest = true;

    function addZeroIfOneDigitvalue(value) {
        if ((value + "").length === 1) {
            value = "0" + value;
        }

        return value;
    }

    while (whileTest) {
        if (hour === 24) {
            break;
        }

        retVal.push(addZeroIfOneDigitvalue(hour) + ":" + addZeroIfOneDigitvalue(minute));

        minute += minutes;
        if (minute >= 60) {
            minute = minute - 60;
            hour++;
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

What would be the best way and approach for selecting 12:00 on every page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-select the value filling the model variable for your select input.

During the $scope setup or in some part of your code when newTestSessionCtrl.formData is filled:

```
newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionTime='12:00';
```

In the HTML for SELECT

```
ng-init="newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionTime='12:00'"
ng-model="newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionTime"
```